# How to add html content into my dom in my case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to get my directive to work. The goal is to add bunch of html when user clicks a button.

I have something like

html

```
<a href='' test-product>click here</a>
```

JS

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('testProduct', ['$compile',
    function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                var include = '<div ng-include="test/product.html"></div>'

                elem.bind('click', function() {
                    elem.append($compile(include)(scope));
                })
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

product.html

```
<div>
   bunch of html here...
</div>
```

For some reason, it doesn't add the product html content as expected. Did I do something wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: put extra quotes in your `ng-include`: `var include = '<div ng-include="\'test/product.html\'"></div>`

Comment: because ngInclude expects string. read it from doc, >angular expression evaluating to URL. If the source is a string constant, make sure you wrap it in single quotes, e.g. src="'myPartialTemplate.html'".

Comment: Thanks guys, please add it as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: BTW, if I were you, I would do it differently. I would use templateURL and simply use ng-if to control it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is that `ng-include` expects a variable that contains a string.

The correct way is to do like so (notice the added quotes):

```
var include = '<div ng-include="\'test/product.html\'"></div>'
```

**Side note:** every time the element is clicked it would add the `ng-include`. Is this what you expect to happen?